# OAuth Consent Screen Dispay Issue

Tags: google-oauth

[image]We have developed an new application which has been integrated with Google File Picker API on Client side application. We are trying to show the OAuth Consent Screen to the end user by showing the Application name " Gsuite Intergration" when the user try to login OAuth Sign In screen.

For running the application from local de[image]velopment server (https://localhost:4200) then OAuth pop up showing  the Application name like "Continue  to  Gsuite Intergration" before the Sign in Header. Its expected behaviour what we are looking. Please refer the "GoogleFilePickerPopup_Localhost.png" attachment.

But when we deploying same application into the server (https://applicationname.domain.com) then OAuth pop up showing as  "Continue  to domain" instead of "Continue to  Gsuite Intergration"  before the Sign in Header. Its not expected behaviour as we need to display the Application name what we have updated Under the Oauth Consent screen. Please refer the "GoogleFilePickerPopup_server.png" attachment.

Comment: can you put up a picture or something showing what you mean.

Comment: @DalmTo - added picture for your references

Comment: Are you using two different clients for local and production?

Comment: @DalmTo - same client ID is using but added redirect URL for local and production

Answer (score 0):

You need to request app verification so your brand configuration can be verified before the name is displayed to your users. See the OAuth App Verification FAQ about circumstances under which verification is needed: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#circumstances

Comment: Thanks for sharing the OAuth App Verfiication FAQ. I have already submitted for OAuth App verification by selecting the application type as 'Public'. But my application is not able to reachable by google while they verify the application URL. Because the application is internally accessible with in our domain not an external application. So i have submitted case to google to allow us change the application type as "Internal". Now we can able to change the application type but can not able to submit for OAuth App verification for the same.